# Pig - Select multiple top records in group

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to select multiple records sharing the same key from a group, but not sure how to filter this.

For example, with the below data:

> D1,20130701,M1,V1
>
> D1,20130701,M2,V2
>
> D1,20130702,M1,V3
>
> D1,20130703,M1,V4
>
> D1,20130703,M2,V5
>
> D2,20130701,M1,V1
>
> D2,20130702,M1,V3
>
> D2,20130703,M1,V4

And a load statement:

```
A = load '/home/hduser/t.csv' 
        using PigStorage(',') 
        as (
            device:chararray, 
            dt:chararray, 
            metric:chararray, 
            value:chararray
        );

C = group A by (device, dt);
```

produces:

> **((D1,20130701),{(D1,20130701,M1,V1),(D1,20130701,M2,V2)})**
>
> ((D1,20130702),{(D1,20130702,M1,V3)})
>
> ((D1,20130703),{(D1,20130703,M1,V4),(D1,20130703,M2,V5)})
>
> **((D2,20130701),{(D2,20130701,M1,V1)})**
>
> ((D2,20130702),{(D2,20130702,M1,V3)})
>
> ((D2,20130703),{(D2,20130703,M1,V4)})

Question is what should I be doing to filter out such that I only get the lines in bold, logic is for each device (D1 / D2 ...), give me the row with the lowest date?

If I were to group only by devices:

```
B = group A by device;
```

I get the following two lines:

> (D1,{(D1,20130701,M1,V1),(D1,20130701,M2,V2),(D1,20130702,M1,V3),(D1,20130703,M1,V4),(D1,20130703,M2,V5)})
>
> (D2,{(D2,20130701,M1,V1),(D2,20130702,M1,V3),(D2,20130703,M1,V4)})

But I can't use limit in the foreach as the number of records per device would be variable.

Any thoughts? Fairly new to Pig!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one approach is

```
 records = LOAD '/user/nubes/ncdc/micro-tab/top.txt' AS (
        device:chararray, 
        dt:int, 
        metric:chararray, 
        value:chararray);


 records_group = group records by (device);

 with_min = FOREACH records_group 
       GENERATE
       FLATTEN(records), MIN(records.dt) ;

 filterRecords = filter with_min by ( $1 == $4 );
```

i/p is

D1  20130701    M1  V1
D1  20130701    M2  V2

D1  20130702    M1  V3

D1  20130703    M1  V4

D1  20130703    M2  V5

D2  20130702    M1  V3

D2  20130703    M1  V4

output is

(D1,20130701,M1,V1,20130701)

(D1,20130701,M2,V2,20130701)

(D2,20130702,M1,V3,20130702)

Comment: Perfect Nag, thank you very much! Gives exactly what I was after.